# What does silent references mean?

Tags: patentability

I'm reading patents allowed subject matter and it states: "the references are also silent (claims xyz)"

what does a silent reference mean?

Comment: A little more context would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Normally it means the subject in question is not addressed one way or another. An example "The text is silent on the issue of initiation and thus does not require courts to define “purposeful personal contact” in such a way."